# Sludge Boiler please help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-mods

I am trying to make a Sludge Boiler and I don't know how. I looked it up and I didn't find anything useful, can somebody help me? By the way I don't know what to try and I am using argraian skies. I would give it sludge and it would not work. when I gave it power and it still did not work... am I missing something?

Comment: feel free to edit my spelling mistakes,,,

Comment: never mind i got it...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All I needed to do was place it and give it sludge and power.